# Acronym + Last Word of the Entered Text. PHP

Tags: php

nickb originally provided these codes. What this originally does is that, when a user enters a text, it will convert it into a acronym by getting the first letters of every word entered. What I want to do now is to include the Last word of the text entered as part of the output. Example: if the user enters Automated Teller Machine, then the output would be: ATM Machine. So far, this is what I came up, unfortunately, I am at a loss right now and is desperate to get this working. Please help.

```
function convert($text) 
{
    $acronym = array();
    $text2 = explode(' ', $text);
    foreach(explode( ' ', $text) as $word)
    {                   
        $acronym[] = strtoupper( $word[0]);
    }
    $count = str_word_count($acronym); 
    array_push($acronym, $text2[$count]);
    echo $text2[$count];
    return implode('', $acronym);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're off-by-one - use `$count-1` in the array.

However, your code can be improved to this:

```
function convert($text) {
    return preg_replace('/\b(.).*?\b\s*/',"$1",$text).strrchr($text," ");
}
// input: convert("Department of Redundancy Department");
// output: DoRD Department
```

Comment: +1 for incomprehensible regex solution

Comment: Thanks for your help @Kolink, however the code of you provided gives this output:

ATMachine Machine

What I need is to have an output which looks like:
ATM Machine

Comment: **NOTE** @user1242749 Kolink means in this line: `array_push($acronym, $text2[$count]);` use `$count-1` instead of `$count`, since in an array with 3 items, the last item is at `[2]`.

Comment: I corrected the error, @user1242749.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that it's not clear to you what the code does. So let's write new code from scratch, but just don't copy it over but you should type it. All functions I use here are documented in the PHP manual. If a function is new to you or you don't know about the one or other parameter, just read it up and learn:

```
$words = str_word_count($text, 2);
```

This line of code extracts all words from `$text` into an array `$words`.

To get the last word, you only need to obtain the last array entry:

```
$last_word = end($words);
```

So this is already half the work to be done. Now you want to extract all first letters:

```
$first_letters = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $first_letters[] = substr($word, 0, 1);
}
```

Having that done, all first letters are in the array `$first_letters` and the last word is in the string variable `$last_word`. With one caveat. If there were no words in the `$text`, then this won't work. Just saying, check that yourself.

So now let's compile the final string:

```
$buffer = implode('', $first_letters);
```

is an easy way to convert the array into a string. And then you only need to add a space and the last word:

```
$buffer .= ' ';
```

That is adding a space character (obvious, right?) and not finally:

```
$buffer .= $last_word;
```

brings everything together.

Happy coding.